# "ErrorAccessDenied" when getting user photos with Microsoft Graph API v1.0

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm getting an "**ErrorAccessDenied**" when attempting to get user photos with the Microsoft Graph API v1.0. I have approx 200 users, and I'm getting this error for around 1 in 10 user photos (the others work fine).

I can get user profile info fine with:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenantID.onmicrosoft.com/users/someUserId/
```

But for some users, attempting to get a photo:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenantID.onmicrosoft.com/users/someUserId/photo
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenantID.onmicrosoft.com/users/someUserId/photo/$value
```

returns "ErrorAccessDenied":

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "ea95a205-23c1-4f3c-b8d5-6ab1dcff0a2e",
      "date": "2015-11-26T00:02:11"
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine if I switch back to the beta endpoint, it's only an issue on v1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requests are correct. You are getting errors on some users due to those users not having the right build with a fix that is rolling out. Apologies for the inconvenience, the deployment should complete in a few days. Note, this issue was captured in the release notes: https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/overview/release_notes

Comment: Thanks Yina. Good to know it will be fixed soon, although I couldn't find a mention of this issue in the release notes.

Comment: Sorry Steph.  The latest release notes have been updated on GitHub here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/content/overview/release_notes.md, but the web version on http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/overview/release_notes has not been refreshed yet. Apologies for this.