# How to check other user availability with Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I'm trying to implement checking availability for specific user (actually a room) in O365 calendar. I'm using Graph API as it's recommended by Microsoft.

My first approach was using POST on https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/findMeetingTimes with the message body prepared according to template given in [Graph API Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). On the API Explorer everything seems to work fine but when I try to run exactly the same request with my applications token I receive 403:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "b130177d-e138-4cc7-8e72-5d3529a9dc24",
      "date": "2017-03-21T08:47:10"
    }
  }
}
```

I checked the app's delegated permissions in AAD and they seem to be fine. For Microsoft Graph those are granted:

- Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared
- Calendars.Read.Shared
- Calendars.ReadWrite
- Calendars.Read

I get exactly the same response (403) when I try to simply list user's events: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users//events In Graph API Explorer 500 is returned.

I found the following bug description: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/559 (and probably [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928681/erroraccessdenied-when-getting-user-photos-with-microsoft-graph-api-v1-0)) Is it related with the issues above?

Any clue what I might be doing wrong?

Is there any other way to achieve the same using different endpoint or API assuming that I still want to use oAuth for authorization?

I will be grateful for any hint

---

Update: [Outlook Calendar API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#FindMeetingTimes) seems to work. Still appreciate any ideas why Graph API doesn't?

Comment: Can you please validate that you have the right permission scopes in you token? you can paste your access token on jwt.calebb.net/ to decode it and look for the scp claim

Comment: `scp: "Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.All Calendars.ReadWrite User.Read"`

Answer (score -1):

The `FindMeetingAPI` needs A work or a school account . If you are logging in using your personal email ID , you might not be able to login. Moreover , you need to set permissions to `Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.All Calendars.ReadWrite User.Read"`

Comment: I have both the permissions and organization account so it's not the case

Comment: @Aproov I haven't switch to Graph API from that time but the [issue on GH](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/559) is still opened and active (commented yesterday) so I guess it's not resolved